# Variables with messages

Tags: php, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a messages.property file in my spring boot application. Something like:

```
welcome=Hello {0} welcome to my page
```

Now I can access this through thymeleaf:

```
<th th:text="#{welcome(${Firstname})}"></th>
```

But what I want to do is to display: Hello John Doe, welcome to my page.
Where John and Doe are different variables I would inject into the welcome message.

Maybe my property file would now look something like: `message= Hello {0} {1}, Welcome to my page` 
Is there a way to accomplish this in spring/thymeleaf?

Comment: Can you not make use of sessions or cookies?

Comment: I don't want to I want to get message value from property file, which is static, and can only be edited from the messages.properties file

Answer (score 0):

Change your property file like this: `message=Hello {0}, Welcome to my page`
and call the label like this: `<th th:text="#{welcome(${varialbe})}"></th>`

Comment: Great this solves it. But I have now edited my question. Take a look and see if there's a way out for this. Thanks.

Comment: Not that experienced with Thymeleaf but add both between the `()` brackets separated by a `,`?